# BIOS unable to recognize GPT drive in UEFI boot mode

Tags: bios, uefi, windows-11-upgrade

I am asking this question from my Windows 11 Surface laptop, which is working fine.

The problem I'm having is with my desktop PC which I built myself, and is running Windows 10. I am trying to upgrade to Windows 11, and was told that I must have TPM 2.0 and Secure Boot enabled. So, I have some relative experience working with OSs and BIOS configuration, and I am successfully able to enable TPM 2.0 and Secure Boot in my BIOS (B450M PRO-VDH MAX Motherboard).

The problem, however, is that the BIOS will not allow me to enable TPM 2.0 and Secure Boot without enabling CSM, disabling LEGACY + UEFI boot, and go to strict UEFI boot. When I do this, my SSD with my Windows 10 installation is not recognized.

I have confirmed that the drive in question is GPT, not MBR, so it seems that's not likely to be the issue, as Microsoft's documentation confirms that GPT is the expected format for Windows 11. I have tried to search for this same issue but am having trouble finding any next steps.

Based on everything I can find online, UEFI is enabled, Secure Boot and TPM 2.0 are enabled, my SSD is GPT not MBR which is all as it should be but yet with this configuration my GPT drive is not being recognized.

Comment: We need some screenshots.  We need screenshots of your partition layout for system disk using Disk Management.  Provide us a screenshot of System Information showing if your current installation is in UEFI or Legacy Mode. We need to know what processor you have exactly.  Since TPM 2.0 and Secure Boot are independent requirements, I would confirm if you are able to enable, only one of them (specifically Secure Boot).  Please use the [edit] feature to provide this information. This information is required since you are saying, a process that should work, is not working for you.

Comment: Have you read any pages, such as "How to enable TPM 2.0 for Windows 11"   https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/technology/how-to-enable-tpm-20-for-windows-11/ar-AAPD0qd

Answer (score 0):

W11 requirements aren't just TPM and SB actually (even though those are certainly the two standing out). Anyhow nothing hard to figure out with [WhyNotWin11](https://github.com/rcmaehl/WhyNotWin11/).

FWIW though MSI motherboards use(d?) to have some [funny](https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/cant-turn-off-csm-because-display-device-does-not-support-uefi-gop-graphics-output-protocol.297770/) CSM auto-switching/forcing mechanism for when they detect a graphics card that dosn't support the UEFI native video protocol. You can try to [update](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/B450M-PRO-VDH-MAX/support#bios) your firmware with the one released a few months ago, if you think that doesn't apply to you.. but be warned that also conversely created a few [headaches](https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?threads/warning-about-the-new-secure-boot-bios-when-using-an-older-graphics-card.376415/) for many people.